# how to read a text file in c and then split each line into tokens?

Tags: c, string, pointers, stdin

The input text file has some numbers per line, numbers are split by space. The first two lines only got one number, and the following lines got three. What I want to do is read each line of the input and store these numbers.

This is what I've got so far:

```
    int
    main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        int n = 0;
        char buff[MAX_STRING_LEN]; //MAX_STRING_LEN is defined as 64
        while (fgets(buff,MAX_STRING_LEN, stdin) != NULL) {
            char temp;
            if (n == 0) {
                sscanf(buff, "%s", &temp);
                int h_num = (int)temp;
            } else if (n == 1) {
                sscanf(buff, "%s", &temp);
                int s_num = (int)temp;
            } else {
                sscanf(buff, "%s", &temp);
                char *token;
                token = strtok(&temp, " ");
                int i = 0;
                int a,b,c;
                while (token != NULL) {
                    if (i == 0) {
                        a = (int)token;
                        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
                    } else if (i == 1) {
                        b = (int)token;
                        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
                    } else {
                        c = (int)token;
                        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
                    }
                    i++;
                }
            }
            n++;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

The print statement I used to test my code is like:

```
    printf("%d\n",h_num);
    printf("%d\n%d\n%d\n",a,b,c);
```

I created a text file like this:

```
23
34
4 76 91
```

but the output is not what I expected, it's the address of the pointer I think. (I'm stuck with pointer again =( )
Could someone help me to point out what the problem is? Appreciate it.

Comment: Why don't you use `fscanf(fp, "%d",&num)`?

Comment: Three calls to `fscanf` with the right format string would be enough. No loops, no `strtok`, nothing complicated.

Comment: Your code has MANY problems. `sscanf(buff, "%s", &temp);` trying to scan a string into a `char` , using `a = (int)token;` etc

Comment: @CoolGuy it seems that `fscanf` is asking for a FILE pointer, so how can I use it to manipulate with each line?

Comment: Are you redirecting input from a file? If so, use `fscanf(stdin, "%d",&num)`

Comment: `int h_num, s_num, a, b, c; fscanf(stdin, "%d %d %d %d %d", &h_num, &s_num, &a, &b, &c);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, I can see,

```
int h_num = (int)temp;
```

and

```
int s_num = (int)temp;
```

No, that is not how you convert an *aphanumeric string* to `int`.

You need to use [`strtol()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) for this purpose.

Then,

```
sscanf(buff, "%s", &temp);
```

is wrong. `temp` is a `char`, you got to use `%c` for that.

My suggestion for a better approach:

1. Read a complete line from file using [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets)
2. tokenize the input using [`strtok()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok), using *space* () as *delimiter*, then convert the token (if not NULL) to `int` using [`strtol()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol)
3. continue untill the returned token is NULL

In this case, your code will be much more *generic*, as don't need to bother seperately about the *number* of `int`s present in each line.

Comment: `strtol()` why not `atoi` ?

Comment: @Eregrith `strtol()` is more robust, and can differenciate between a valid `0` input and error case.

Comment: If you foresee this expanding to recognize more tokens in the future, a little more complicated (but much more robust) solution is Flex and Bison. Or similar lexers/parsers. Windows versions are available too. http://aquamentus.com/flex_bison.html

Comment: @SouravGhosh I was trying to use `sscanf`in this way: `sscanf(buff, "%d", &h_num)`. Then I do `printf("%d",h_num)`. But when I compile it, it says that  `h_num` was undeclared. What's the point of that?

Comment: @LeaneLi You have declared in the if-block.